# Is there a way I can get my site's favicon updated for Safari (both desktop & mobile)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte, sveltekit

I've been working on a project using SvelteKit and I have yet to figure out why my favicon is not showing up correctly on Safari (both desktop & mobile). Instead, it's actually picking up the favicon from a site I have linked on my footer! This is what's in the head of my app.html file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Movie Hunt" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/QzdVah9.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Browse through genres of movies or search for a particular movie title and find out if they are available for rent or currently being streamed online."/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://movie-hunt-demo.vercel.app/" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="627" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Londrina+Shadow&family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Yellowtail&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4dd3342d23.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%sveltekit.assets%/styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.ico?v=2">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x32" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png?v=2" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="/images/favicon-16x16.png?v=2" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/apple-touch-icon.png?v=2">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico?v=2" color="#000000">
    <link rel="android-chrome" sizes="192x192" href="%sveltekit.assets%/images/android-chrome-192x192.png">
    <title>Movie Hunt</title>
    %sveltekit.head%
</head>
```

This is on my footer and where I'm assuming my project is picking up the yellow favicon somehow:

```
<a class="coffee_a" href="https://www.buymeacoffee.com/rickydlgd" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"><i class="fa-solid fa-mug-hot"></i></a>
```

It's really strange. The correct favicon does show up on other browsers as I've tested the site on chrome, firefox, and brave so far. Safari is the only one picking up the yellow favicon from buymeacoffee.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Here's a link to my project: [Movie Hunt](https://movie-hunt-demo.vercel.app/)

Below is a screenshot of what I've been seeing:

[image: Screenshot of my site showing the 'buy me a coffee' favicon instead of my own]

Answer (score 0):

Safari has suddenly updated the favicon to the correct one and I didn't change any of the code... I guess it takes a couple days for it to update? Anyway, just leaving this here in case anyone runs into this issue. Waiting a couple days was the answer.